# Running Grails 2.3.1 in debug mode from linux

Tags: linux, grails, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run Grails 2.3.1 en debug mode either from console or IntelliJ IDEA 12, but I always get the following error:

```
grails run-app --debug-fork
| Running Grails application
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
```

Comment: Pls share your grails.project.fork in BuildConfig.groovy file.

Comment: @emilan here is mine :
grails.project.fork = [
        development: [maxMemory: 1024, minMemory: 64, debug: true],
        test       : [maxMemory: 1024, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon: true],
        run        : [maxMemory: 1024, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve: false],
        war        : [maxMemory: 1024, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve: false],
        console    : [maxMemory: 1024, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]
you have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I configure my IDEA Debug mode.
For grails <2.4

I'm doing next:
1. grails-debug run-app
It's opening port 5005 and waiting for your IDE to connect
2. Go to IDEA and hit "bug" button
3. Your grails console automatically runs application

For grails 2.4
1. "grails --debug run-app"
2. Hit "bug" button

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows

- i switched and reswitched the grails version with gvm default ...
- i checked a fresh copy